# Redirect command line input to file, then turn over to standard input

Tags: windows, cmd, stdin

I have a command-line program that I would like to launch, execute a few commands automatically, and then turn the input over to the standard input.  The problem with using command line input redirection is that as soon as the commands execute, the program quits.  Instead of quitting immediately, I'd like to take over control from that point.

Is there any way to do this?  I haven't been able to find anything that works.

Comment: Check out [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/)

Comment: @dbenham I considered doing so (big fan of autoIt), but I'll be packaging this for a number of others so I would rather not require everyone to install other programs just to get this to work. Do you know of anything built-in that could help?